# Masking With A Grayscale Image With PHP And ImageMagick

Tags: php, imagemagick

I am trying to create a grayscale mask in Imagemagick (v7.0.11) that behaves like a layer mask in Photoshop where white areas are completely opaque and black areas are fully masked.

```
   function grayscaleMaskTest () {

    //Create a black and white mask
    $mask = new Imagick();
    $mask->newImage(300, 300, "#ffffff");
    $mask->setImageType(IMAGICK::IMGTYPE_GRAYSCALE);
    $mask->setImageFormat('gif');

    //draw black circle
    $draw = new ImagickDraw(); 
    $draw->setStrokeWidth(1);
    $draw->setStrokeOpacity(1);
    $draw->setStrokeColor(new ImagickPixel("#000000"));
    $draw->setFillColor(new ImagickPixel("#000000"));
    $draw->circle(300/2, 300/2, 300/2, 300/2 + 100);
    $mask->drawImage($draw);
    //$mask->writeImage('C:\Users\Mike\Documents\images\mask.png'); //export mask

    //Create final image
    $final = new Imagick();
    $final->newImage(300, 300, "#FF0000");

    //Not sure if I had this right but tried writing the mask data to the alpha channel
    //$final->compositeImage($mask, IMAGICK::COMPOSITE_COPYOPACITY, 0, 0, IMAGICK::CHANNEL_ALPHA);
    $final->compositeImage($mask, IMAGICK::COMPOSITE_COPYOPACITY, 0, 0);

    $final->writeImage('C:\Users\Mike\Documents\images\final.png');
}
```

The mask looks like this :

[image]

The desired result from this code if it worked would be this (minus the fake transparency) :

[image]

Comment: Post the desired  result from Photoshop showing what you want to achieve for the same images. I do not fully understand the issue.

Comment: @fmw42 -  Hey! Above, using COPYALPHA, the alpha values are set indifferent of grayscale value. The mask's circle could be any color with the same result, In Photoshop, white  indicates full opacity of pixels and black indicates fully masked. Image 3 shows what the correct result would look like. In the areas that are white red would show through when compositing with a solid red image, in the areas that are black on the mask the final image is transparent. I think I just need to create a grayscale mask with no alpha channel and use COPYOPACITY but I can't get it to work.

Comment: @fmw42 - To reduce it even further, with the black/white mask above I want white to be fully opaque and black to be transparent on the final image when compositing the mask with another solid color image. Same as applying a mask layer to an image in Photoshop.

Comment: Just invert your mask. See PHP Imagick negateImage().

Comment: No go, sadly. Inverting the mask doesn't help because my code still isn't setting opacity based on the grayscale values of the mask file.

Answer (score 0):

With help from @fmw42 this ended up working. Thanks!

```
//Create a black and white mask
$mask = new Imagick();
$mask->newImage(300, 300, "#ffffff");

//draw black circle
$draw = new ImagickDraw();
$draw->setStrokeWidth(1);
$draw->setStrokeOpacity(1);
$draw->setStrokeColor(new ImagickPixel("#0"));
$draw->setFillColor(new ImagickPixel("#0"));
$draw->circle(300/2, 300/2, 300/2, 300/2 + 100);
$mask->drawImage($draw);
$mask->setImageMatte(false); //<-------This got it going!

//Create final image
$final = new Imagick();
$final->newImage(300, 300, "#FF0000");

$final->compositeImage($mask, imagick::COMPOSITE_COPYOPACITY, 0, 0);`
```